# How to isolate ansible output based on key

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to isolate the output of the ansible playbook however it says `"output.stdout": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`

My playbook code is:
`---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Register variable
      shell: "echo {{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "one"
        - "two"
      register: output
    - debug:
        var: output.stdout`

Interestingly , the debug output works fine if i dont isolate it using `stdout` key.

```
TASK [Register variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=one)
changed: [localhost] => (item=two)

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": true,
                "cmd": "echo one",
                "delta": "0:00:00.002986",
                "end": "2020-01-24 00:20:57.226744",
                "failed": false,
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "echo one",
                        "_uses_shell": true,
                        "argv": null,
                        "chdir": null,
                        "creates": null,
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop

> When you use register with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a results attribute that is a list of all responses from the module

Thus:

```
output.results[0].stdout
output.results[1].stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to loop into a separate .yml file (via include), which will perform a gentle operation + output. For example:

main.yml:

```
- name: RUN start.yml
  include: start.yml
  vars:
    app: "{{ item.name }}"
  static: false
  with_items: "{{ list_items }}"
```

start.yml in same role:

```
- name: "Run {{ app }}"
  command: './runapp.sh {{ app }}'
  register: start_app_register
  no_log: True

- debug:
    msg: '{{ start_app_register.stdout }}'
```